# Why isn't my php move file script actually moving the file?

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I am uploading files to a server using php and while the move_uploaded_file function returns no errors, the file is not in the destination folder. As you can see I am using the exact path from root, and the files being uploaded are lower than the max size.

```
$target = "/data/array1/users/ultimate/public_html/Uploads/2010/";  
//Write the info to the bioHold xml file.
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('bioHold.xml');
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$root = $xml->firstChild;
$player = $xml->createElement("player");
$image = $xml->createElement("image");
$image->setAttribute("loc", $target.basename($_FILES['image']['name']));
$player->appendChild($image);
$name = $xml->createElement("name", $_POST['name']);
$player->appendChild($name);
$number = $xml->createElement("number", $_POST['number']);
$player->appendChild($number);
$ghettoYear = $xml->createElement("ghettoYear", $_POST['ghetto']);
$player->appendChild($ghettoYear);
$schoolYear = $xml->createElement("schoolYear", $_POST['school']);
$player->appendChild($schoolYear);
$bio = $xml->createElement("bio", $_POST['bio']);
$player->appendChild($bio);
$root->appendChild($player);
$xml->save("bioHold.xml");
//Save the image to the server.
$target = $target.basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))
    echo 'It is a file <br />';
if(!(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target))) {
    echo $_FILES['image']['error']."<br />";
}
else {
    echo $_FILES['image']['error']."<br />";
    echo $target;   
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Eric R.

Comment: what comes out from the script (i mean the $target...etc)

Comment: does your script has write permission on the folder?

Comment: It has write permissions, and error outputs 0, $target outputs the path and the proper filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most like this is a permissions issue. I'm going to assume you don't have any kind of direct shell access to check this stuff directly, so here's how to do it from within the script:

Check if the `$target` directory exists:

```
$target = '/data/etc....';
if (!is_dir($target)) {
    die("Directory $target is not a directory");
}
```

Check if it's writeable:

```
if (!is_writable($target)) {
    die("Directory $target is not writeable");
}
```

Check if the full target filename exists/is writable - maybe it exists but can't be overwritten:

```
 $target = $target . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
 if (!is_writeable($target)) {
     die("File $target isn't writeable");
 }
```

Beyond that:

```
if(!(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target))) {
    echo $_FILES['image']['error']."<br />";
}
```

Echoing out the `error` parameter here is of no use, it refers purely to the upload process. If the file was uploaded correctly, but could not be moved, this will still only echo out a `0` (e.g. the UPLOAD_ERR_OK constant). The proper way of checking for errors goes something like this:

```
if ($_FILES['images']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    // file was properly uploaded
    if (!is_uploaded_File(...)) {
        die("Something done goofed - not uploaded file");
    }
    if (!move_uploaded_file(...)) {
        echo "Couldn't move file, possible diagnostic information:"
        print_r(error_get_last());
        die();

    }
} else {
    die("Upload failed with error {$_FILES['images']['error']}");
}
```

Comment: So this was MOSTLY right. Issue explained: The folder "2010" that was in "Uploads" was writable so all of your checks passed without a problem. However, Uploads itself was not writable. Doing all these checks made me think about that. So when I made Uploads writable it worked beautifully. Thanks Marc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that whoever is hosting your pages has the settings configured to allow you to upload and move files. Most will disable these functions as it's a sercurity risk.

Just email them and ask whether they are enabled.

Hope this helps.

Comment: PS Have you tested the script on local machine.

Comment: As of last year I was able to upload to the server. I will check with them to see.

Answer (score 0):

your calls to is_uploaded_file and move_uploaded_file vary. for is_uploaded_file you are checking the 'name' and for move_uploaded_file you are passing in 'tmp_name'. try changing your call to move_uploaded_file to use 'name'

Comment: `move_uploaded_file()` requires the server-side temp name as the source, which is in `tmp_name`. Changing it to `name` is wrong as that's the client-side original filename, which would cause the move to fail with 'no such file'.